# Why use enumerator in ruby

Tags: ruby

I stumbled upon such example:

```
file = "./path"
var = Enumerator.new do |y|
CSV.foreach(file) do |row|
            y.yield(row)
    end
end
```

Question is, why store data of any kind, inside enumerators, insted of arrays? what is the difference in behaviour between whats above and this:

```
file = "./path"
var = []
CSV.foreach(file) do |row|
    var << row
end
```

when i want to something with the data it looks the same for both cases:

```
var.each {|row| puts row}
```

So what are the advantages and disadvantages of such constructions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, iterators can be used to lazily generate a sequence of objects. 
This is the main advantage when creating a lazy enumeration compared to creating a collection of items which is much more efficient.

For example, if your enumerator loop iterates over just the first 5 items of 3 million items then that's all yield returns, and you didn't build up a collection of 1 million items internally first.

So, you do not need to load all the 3 millions items just for your callee function can continue and executes the rest of the code.

Iterators are means for returning sequences.

Sometimes The sequence might even be **infinite**.

It brings the functional programming concept of lazy evaluation to Ruby – at least for enumerations.

There is a huge difference between returning a collection and returning a collection generator.

Comment: This is true as of now, but notice that lazy enumerators were added later. Enumerators had existed without them.

Comment: @sawa The _lazy enumerator_ feature is an adapter between `Enumerator` and `Enumarable` to easily support laziness for enumerables.

Answer (score 0):

Too see the difference of the code add a `puts` within the loops.

```
seq = (1..3)
enum = Enumerator.new do |y|
  seq.each do |i|
    puts "Grabbing #{i} with enumerator"
    y.yield(i)
  end
end
enum.each { |i| puts "Taken #{i} from enumerator" }

# Grabbing 1 with enumerator
# Taken 1 from enumerator   
# Grabbing 2 with enumerator
# Taken 2 from enumerator   
# Grabbing 3 with enumerator
# Taken 3 from enumerator        

array = []
seq.each do |i|
  puts "Grabbing #{i} with array"
  array << i
end
array.each { |i| puts "Taken #{i} from array" }

# Grabbing 1 with array     
# Grabbing 2 with array     
# Grabbing 3 with array     
# Taken 1 from array        
# Taken 2 from array        
# Taken 3 from array
```

Like mentioned by Tal Avissar the `Enumerator` fetches the value when it's needed which is called *lazy evaluation*. This behavoir is a benefit in some situations.

```
# infinite number sequence
numbers = Enumerator.new do |y|  
  n = 0                          
  loop { y.yield(n += 1) }       
end                              
puts numbers.take(3).join(', ')  
# 1, 2, 3
```

When dealing with huge or infinite sequences the difference is quite important.